# adjust size of fixed object when screen size changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to make a table cell "fixed" (DONE) but I also want the size of the table cell to visualy adjust when a user changes the screen size (cntrl + ect.). Can someone offer suggestions on how to solve this?

```
<td valign="top" style="padding-left:5px; position:fixed; width:38%;">
<table width="98%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td>
<video ...></video>
</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"any suggestions on how this company handles the information on the right? girlfriendnyc.com/#/portfolio"

You mean something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/21/

The jquery plugin that is doing this sets elements fixed whatever margin from the top of the page.  With an optional limit, it will unfix the elements and have them continue to scroll up the page, allowing the next element to scroll into view and fix at the top of the page until it hit its limit.

Here is the code usage for this scenario (the fiddle above):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cart1').scrollToFixed( { marginTop: 10, limit: 400 } );
    $('#cart2').scrollToFixed( { marginTop: 10, limit: 800 } );
});
```

Here is the link to the plugin and its source:

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.  Web browsers don't send events or post messages accessible to Javascript when a user zooms.

Comment: Is there another way to make an element fixed?

Comment: any suggestions on how this company handles the information on the right? http://www.girlfriendnyc.com/#/portfolio